# Import brush set

Tags: add-on, import

I had a problem in importing  brushes in blender 2.79, because in the user preferences there is no import brush add-on. So, Now what to do to solve this. Did blender 2.79 support this. I think,it should ,But how, I don't know.

Comment: How does "sapling-addon" tag help to describe your question? To import brushes from another file use Append or Link options and choose Brush category

Comment: @Mr Zak That was probably the only tag the user could "Afford". It's ridiculous that you cant post without entering at least one tag, but the majority of the tags are off limits to new users...the ones asking most of the questions.

Comment: @InternetWarriors they could use "import" tag perfectly fine. New users are limited in creating new tags which does have quite serious reasons, while they can use existing tags and at least "import" was available (because it was created back in year 2013).

Answer (score 2):

Activate the Brush addon from User Preferences -> Addon

If u have older version download the addon from [here](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/BrushSet)

Launch Blender, then open the User Preferences. Go to the Addons tab.
Go to the Import-Export Addons and enable the script.

[image]

[image]

select the import BrushSet from the file menu

[image]

select the folder with your textures and press import

[image]

Edit Mode

```
Unwrap your mesh and add a new texture to paint on.
```

Texture Paint Mode

Under texture tab, press the field which will pop up the texture selection.

[image]

all your textures should now be loaded there and you can start painting.

[image]

Comment: This addon doesn't appear in the list of addons packaged with Blender on my end, 2.79a on Mac.

Comment: @Craig D Jones I believe you can find that add on here. It does not appear in the windows version either. https://github.com/sftd/blender-addons-contrib/blob/master/io_import_BrushSet.py

Answer (score 2):

You can get the addon from the original author's [github](https://github.com/kromar/Blender_Addons/blob/master/addons_contrib/io_import_BrushSet.py)

and there is also another addon that is [similar](https://github.com/amb/blender-scripts/blob/master/load_alphas.py) in function