# Import Brushset add_on

Tags: texturing, add-on, import

I still dont have "brush" add_on in "user preferences" . But I need it. I have Blender 2.79. Why it is not providing this add_on.I have to import texture brushes and Blender 2.79 also dont have "import" add_on, not a single one.It only has "Export" add_on.Plz tell me what is the problem with my blender.Here is the picture:[image]
i am talking about this:[image][image] but this is not actually appearing

Comment: What addon are you trying to install? It's likely addon with "brush" in the name won't appear there by default except for [Sculpt/Paint Brush Menus](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?417167-Sculpt-Paint-Brush-Tools-menu) which is another addon.  Did you download addon files and put it into folder where Blender searches for them? If you're unsure how to do that easiest way is to use Install Addon From File button and point Blender to source files location.

Comment: @MrZak .. I was talking about the thing which i mention again my my question

Comment: How is this different from your previous question on the same topic? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92302/import-brush-set

Answer (score 1):

The Import BrushSet addon is not an official addon that is included with blender releases. While it may be added to future versions, you will need to download and install it manually until then.

The BrushSet addon can be found in the Blender Add-ons Contrib repo and as it is a single file, you can easily download the one file and install it. Save the file from [this link](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender-addons-contrib.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/io_import_BrushSet.py), click the *Install Add-On* button and select the downloaded file.

Comment: ok... but in which format i have to save this text file(extension)?

Comment: It is a python script - a plain text file with a `.py` extension, rename it if your browser saves it with `.txt`